# How to set and get a value in a service - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have written a service described below

```
myApp.service('dashboardPath', function(){


    var path;

      return {
        path: path
      }

      this.path = function(value){
        path = value;
      }

});
```

am setting the value of **path** in sessionsCtrl like this dashboardPath.path = "student_dashboard" and i can access the value of path in any controller like dashboardPath.path which is returning the correct value, but if i reload the page the value of **path** is gone(it says "undefined"). Is my above service defined properly?

Comment: as far as i know if you refresh your page it is totally normal that the value goes undefined, what you need is to use [local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: Are you reloading by downloading the JS again? If so, it is completely normal that the value would be undefined. If you want to persist something with reloads you should use the browsers storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refresh the page the value will disappear because the app reloads. What you need is persistence of data:

```
myApp.service('dashboardPath', function(){

    var path = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('path'));
    this.path = function(value){
        path = value;
        localStorage.setItem("path", path);

      };

      return {
        path: path
      }

});
```

Comment: This leaves me with another question. What i need is when a user logs in i decide the dashboard path based on some condition. Am trying to set the path using a service, now i also have a link that takes the user to dashboard, i can fetch the path from the service and already said the value is cleaned up when the page is reloaded, so now i don't have the correct path when user clicks on the **dashboard link**. For this **localStorage** is the only solution? or is there any other technique that angularjs provides to achieve this?

Comment: you can also use cookies to persist data (ng-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Services are singleton objects that will live for the duration of your application. Refreshing the page reloads all the code and ditches the old memory. Your code is working correctly.

If you want to persist data between page refreshes, try using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Comment: or even better an native angular service https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

this code looks strange:

```
myApp.service('dashboardPath', function(){

    var path;
    return {
        path: path
    }
    this.path = function(value){
        path = value;
    }

});
```

1. `return` sentences are not needed since such function is called using `new` operator. yoor code should be:

   ```
   myApp.service('dashboardPath', function(){

       var path;

       this.path = path;

   });
   ```
2. you need to -actually- store the value. By having it in just a variable, the context will be reset when you refresh, and you will still get the `undefined` you say. You should store it in one of three places:

   - server-side: use ajax ($http) to `get` and `post` the value.
   - client-side LocalStorage - [See @bto.rdz's comment](http://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)
   - cookies

   in any of such places you'll need to have a setter and getter for such values:

   ```
   this.getPath = function(){ ... };
   this.setPath = function(v){ ... };
   ```

   instead of the plain member variable `path`.